# Computer left unplugged now boots with beep codes saying graphic card not working

Tags: graphics-card, bios

I'm trying to resurrect an old computer which was left unplugged for probably too long. Here's the setup :

- **Box**: HP Pavilion Media Center m8000
- **Motherboard**: [ASUS P5BW-LA](https://support.hp.com/lv-en/document/c00748726)
- **Graphic Card**: ATI Radeon X1650

There's no video port on the motherboard, so it requires a video card. Booting up, I get two short beeps and one long beep, repeated five times, which is the standard HP/Compaq beep code for an issue with the graphic card: “[Unable to initialize video or video card required but not installed](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c02222922).”

I haven't touched that computer for a while, and the card was still firmly plugged in. Graphic card fan is working. Visual check of the graphic cards, motherboard and other components shows no damage, no bulging capacitors. Re-seating the graphic card did not solve the issue.

Maybe the button battery got bad since it's an old computer and the BIOS lost its memory for being unplugged for too long. My questions are:

- Is there a way to find out whether the BIOS is at fault or whether the graphic card is to blame?
- If the issue is with the BIOS, is it possible to reprogram it?

Comment: Old computer = open the case and look for bulging capacitors. This can occur because of long term non-use.

Comment: How long has the computer been left unplugged? Unplugging a computer and tossing it aside should not cause issues like this. Also, do you need the computer itself to boot up? Or do you need data off the system hard drive? Because honestly if you just need data off of the hard drive you are much better off just pulling it out and using an external drive case or adapter to connect it to another PC and get the data that way.

Comment: Have you tried opening up the PC and reseating the graphics card? (Unplugging it and plugging it back in against ). If you do this, make sure the PC is off and keep your body in contact with metal in the case. (There is debate about the best way to ground yourself @sdmark answer is good if you have a static strap, but touching metal can bring you to the same potential as the case in a pinch)

Comment: Quarantine means everyone and my grandma needs a basic machine to access the internet. Good tip if I wanted to save the HDD, but my goal is to wipe it and install a lightweight linux distro, if I can get it to work. Thanks still!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really simple test would be to plug another GPU into the mobo.

My first plan would be re-seating the GPU. Remove it and reinstall it.

If the problem persists, either check the GPU in another machine or check another GPU in this one.

Comment: Big shocker here, but when the motherboard gives you beep codes saying your graphic card doesn't work, it means your graphic card doesn't work. Replacing the old graphic card with a new one solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Always wear an anti-static wrist strap if possible. With the computer plugged in but off, touch the inside of the metal case. If the outlet is well grounded that will help to discharge some static electricity before you touch anything else. Then UNPLUG the computer and touch the metal case again.

The first thing I would try is to remove all add-in cards except the video card. Then remove and firmly re-seat the video card.

Next thing to try is to re-seat the memory chips, carefully.

If those two actions don't help, get a replacement CMOS battery. It's a 3v Lithium CR2032. I've found them in drugstores, office supply stories and places that carry hearing aid batteries in addition to the usual AA/AAA etc. It will pop up when you push on the retaining clip.

Try clearing the CMOS by following the instructions on that HP page for the P4BW-LA motherboard under "Clearing the BIOS settings".

With any luck, clearing the CMOS will reset the BIOS and you should be good to go.

Comment: I re-seated the video card. Did not pick up anything unusual after a visual check: no bulging capacitors, no traces on the PCB. Same for the motherboard and memory cards. I will buy a new button CMOS battery and keep you updated.

Comment: I tried the new battery and did the "CLEAR_CMOS" with the motherboard's jumpers but no luck. I guess @brad-fox was right and I need to change the graphic card or (hopefully not) the motherboard.

Comment: If you have another computer with the same IO slot configuration (ISA, PCI, PCIe) where you can try that graphics card, that should indicate if it's good or bad. If it's bad, you can usually find a good basic card for under $50 or even less if it's used but guaranteed working.

Comment: I'd rather not try a possibly faulty graphic card in another computer, since that other computer is my main working box. I'll buy an old graphic card with the next batch of stuff I buy online, but it might be another while. Thanks for the help, nonetheless!